# Are questions about pronunciation notation ok?

Tags: discussion, pronunciation

I have a made up word (being used as brand name for a project I'm working on) and I know how it is pronounced and I can write it phonetically, but I need to know how to write the pronunciation with the correct 'notation' as used in dictionaries. Please pardon my ignorance when it comes to terminology.

Is it a valid question to ask on this site? If not, does anyone know where I can find the information please? As it's a made up word I can't use a dictionary to copy it from there.

Thanks

Comment: Dictionaries usually include a pronunciation key somewhere (at least, print dictionaries do, and at least some online dictionaries like the [OED](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-pronunciation/)). Is there any reason you can't use that?

Comment: Check Wikipedia on IPA transcription. It's not on topic here because it's not specific to English, and since you've invented it ex-nihilio, we won't be able to provide any other research or information specific to your word. If, during your research into IP, you come across any other questions about English, feel free to ask.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for the clarification - glad I asked!

Comment: @DanBron I reckon it should be ok. Dictionary transcriptions are English-specific. They cannot describe phonemes or phones of other languages. The transcription of OP's word is going to be English-specific as will be the name of the brand. /sdæ/ for example will be impossible, but /stɑ:/ would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

The phonotactic constraints of English will strictly circumscribe what the pronunciation of your brand name is (so, for example  /sdæ/ will be impossible, but /stɑ:/ would be perfectly fine). In addition, the conventions for the transcription of English are language-specific and not applicable to the phonemic transcription of other languages. So long as your brand name is not already a recognised word (or a homophone of a recognised word)—in which case you can just look the word up in a dictionary and copy the transcription—the question should be on topic for this site. That's how I see it, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, in general, questions about pronunciation notations and their correspondence with actual pronunciation are on-topic.

But you question could easily be off-topic for other reasons, eg 'How do you pronounce this word I made up?' is considered off-topic.

Your question seems to be somewhere in the middle. To make it more on-topic, you'll want to steer things towards the differences between the notations, rather than the specifics of your word. But it would be on-topic to use your new word as an example of the differences between notations.

Or for a specific question 'How do I notate my new word in the system that Merriam-Webster does?' you can always ask on chat and maybe get a quicker answer (or possibly not, depends on who's there when).